# Convert list of LABColors to list of RGBColors

Tags: color

I have a list of LABColors: {{l1,a1,b1},{l2,a2,b2}..{ln,an,bn}}
I want to convert it to a list of RGBColors of same form: {{r1,g1,b1}, {r2,g2,b2}, .. {rn,gn,bn}}

I have been trying for a few hours but I keep running into snags ..

for example:
c1 = LABColor[l1,a1,b1]
-> I get a color swatch

ColorConvert[c1, "RGB"]
-> I get a good transform, but it is a color swatch

ColorConvert[c1, "RGB"] // InputForm
-> I get RGBColor[r1,g1,b1]

and I am stuck here.

I need the result to be in list form {{r1, g1, b1},...}

Thanks for any suggestions, pointers :)

Comment: In Mathematica an RGB color is represented as `RBGColor[r, b, g]`.  You want to replace `RBGColor` with `List`: `rgbcolors /. RGBColor -> List`. Yes/no?

Comment: My list of numerical colors are in LAB space, and I want to convert to a list of RGB numerical values.

Comment: You said, "I get RGBColor[r1,g1,b1]" and I showed how to take it another step...but I have another way...in a sec

Comment: I got it! thanks, that worked! :)

Comment: I couldn't find RBGColor... are you sure it is RBGColor? The documentation says RGBColor, (RGB, not RBG).. just double checking

Comment: Sorry, `RGBColor` -- I'm dyslexic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some LAB color data in the form of an $n\times3$ array of real numbers:

```
labdata = 
  Diagonal[
   ImageData@
    ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], "LAB"]];
```

Here is the conversion to an RGB array:

```
rgb1 = First@
   ImageData@
    ColorConvert[Image[{labdata}, ColorSpace -> "LAB"], "RGB"];
```

Another (slower) way:

```
rgb2 = ColorConvert[labdata, "LAB" -> "RGB"] /. RGBColor -> List
```

Comment: Thanks so much! the (slower) is more to my skill level right now, but perfect for me. 

Thanks again